# combing multiple columns in sql for sum

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I am getting the `cr.credit` value as the multiple of same value. But i need the exact value for that to calculate the total value.Can anyone help me to get the answer.

```
SELECT
  gm.id,
  gm.groupid,
  gm.tktno,
  gm.memberid,
  (COALESCE((g.emdue - ae.dividend), 0)) AS a,
  SUM(ra.debit) AS deb,
  SUM(DISTINCT ra.credit) AS cr,
  COALESCE((SUM(ra.debit) - SUM(ra.credit)), 0) AS b,
  COALESCE(SUM(cr.credit_value), 0) AS c,
  COALESCE((COALESCE((g.emdue - ae.dividend), 0) - COALESCE((SUM(ra.debit) - SUM(ra.credit)), 0)
  - COALESCE(SUM(cr.credit_value), 0)), 0) AS total
FROM groupmember gm
LEFT JOIN runningaccount ra
  ON ra.group_id = gm.groupid
  AND ra.ticket_no = gm.tktno
  AND gm.memberid = ra.member_id
  AND gm.id = ra.group_member_id
LEFT JOIN chitreceipt cr
  ON gm.groupid = cr.groupid
  AND gm.memberid = cr.memberid
  AND gm.tktno = cr.tktno
LEFT JOIN groupnew g
  ON g.id = gm.groupid
LEFT JOIN auctionentry ae
  ON ae.groupid = gm.groupid
GROUP BY gm.memberid,
         gm.groupid,
         gm.tktno
```

Comment: This is mySql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do distinct of that column and then sum so you can get distinct values sum. like

```
sum(distinct COALESCE(cr.credit_value,0))
```

wherever you use it use it like above.

Comment: `nvl()`??? Question is tagged as `MySQL` and there is no `nvl()`. did you rather meant `IsNull()` or `COALESCE()`?

Comment: I used COALESCE() in my query.